# Add Static Row To UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

In my app, I query Parse.com to get a list of groups to populate a UIPickerView.  I want to add one more option to the UIPickerView at the very top that is called "Create New Group", in which it will pull up a UITextField to make a new group and move from there.  How do I go about adding this to all the other fields?  Here is how I have it created so far.

```
-(void)addPickerView{

     __block NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *rejectedNumber = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    [rejectedNumber orderByAscending:@"GroupName"];
    [rejectedNumber findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {



        if (!objects) {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user

            NSLog(@"NotFound");
        } else {
            pickerArray = objects;
            [myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

        }
    }];

     //pickerArray = GoGo;
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.delegate = self;
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setPlaceholder:@"Choose Group"];
    myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                   target:self action:@selector(finishIt)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                     self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             doneButton, nil];
    [toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView = myPickerView;
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}
#pragma mark - Picker View Data source
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [pickerArray count];
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setText:self.theGroup];
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    PFObject *object = pickerArray[row];
    //Assuming "Category" is a string here for your title
    self.theGroup = object[@"GroupName"];
    return object[@"GroupName"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add achieve that in two ways:

1. Add an extra object at the first index of your array for showing *"Create New Group"*
2. You can use tweak the datasource and delegate methods of `UIPickerView`. Like:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerArray count] + 1; // +1 for the additional row
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (row == 0)
    {
        // Create New Group clicked
    }
    else
    {
       // Some other option selected
    }
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *groupName  = "Create New Group";
    if (row != 0)
    {
        PFObject *object = pickerArray[row - 1]; // -1 to handle the array index
        self.theGroup    = object[@"GroupName"];
        groupName        = object[@"GroupName"];
    }
    return groupName;
}
```

Comment: And incase it isn't obvious to the OP, the same `pickerArray[row - 1]` is needed in the `else` block in the `didSelectRow` method.

Comment: Two questions...why is that needed @rmaddy? Everything works without it?  Also, in the `if (row == 0)` line of code, I try to present an alertController but get an error message about attempting to present alert controller on tabbarcontroller whose view is not in hierarchy.

Comment: @user717452: Because your first row represent the "Create new group" item and your array doesn't have that object. So the 1st row of your picker represents the first element(0th index) element of your array. Regarding the alert error you need to provide more info.

Comment: How can I get it to dismiss the pickervjew and pop up the keyboard again when I select the Create New Group?